# How to find the URL of the service or access the service from my desktop?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

This is the result for the command:
kubectl describe service

```
Name:              kubernetes
Namespace:         default
Labels:            component=apiserver
                   provider=kubernetes
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          <none>
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.96.0.1
IPs:               10.96.0.1
Port:              https  443/TCP
TargetPort:        6443/TCP
Endpoints:         192.168.65.4:6443
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>


Name:                     testdeployment
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=testdeployment,version=v01
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.109.218.220
IPs:                      10.109.218.220
LoadBalancer Ingress:     localhost
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30741/TCP
Endpoints:                10.1.0.27:80,10.1.0.28:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

And I have two pods running in the service:
kubectl get pods

```
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
testdeployment-6565bb9664-2ctwn   2/2     Running   0          30m
testdeployment-6565bb9664-7vmv5   2/2     Running   0          30m
```

The service is conneted to two pods.

Please tell me the URL to access the service.

Comment: Did you tried with 'curl localhost` because your NodePort describes with localhost and the port is default port 80.  Better to try with your localhost other wise Host machine public IP from your service description `10.109.218.220`, so you can also try `curl 10.109.218.220`

Answer (score 2):

ClusterIPs are not accessible outside the cluster.

So, if you're planning to access the cluster from outside you cannot do it unless you change something, for example:

- turning the clusterIP into NodePort or LoadBalancer
- add an Ingress to connect to the clusterIP
- forward the request with Kubectl (`kubectl port-forward <int_port> <ext_port>`)

If useful, you can also check the endpoint you created:

```
kubectl get endpoints
```

or

```
kubectl get services
```

Comment: better to add your kubectl commands with `-o wide` option that gives the mapping IP address as well that helps more!